# How to set different color of text for the legends using core plot

Tags: ios, swift, graph, core-plot

I am using core plot to for drawing the graph. My problem is i want to set the legends text color according to line color. I have four scatter plot in one graph, each scatter plot is having different line color.

In the legends it will show line color correctly but i want to change the text color according to line color for each scatter graph title. I have written the following code for the legend.

```
newGraph.legend = CPTLegend(graph: newGraph)
        newGraph.legend?.numberOfRows = UInt(2.0)
        let dataSourceLabelStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
        dataSourceLabelStyle.color = CPTColor.white()
        newGraph.legend?.textStyle       = dataSourceLabelStyle
        newGraph.legend?.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.init(componentRed: 50/244, green: 43/244, blue: 87/244, alpha: 1.0))
        newGraph.legend?.cornerRadius = 5.0
        newGraph.legendDisplacement = CGPoint.init(x: -50, y: 210)
        let fadeInAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadeInAnimation.duration            = 1.0
        fadeInAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        fadeInAnimation.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards
        fadeInAnimation.toValue             = 1.0
        dataSourceLinePlot.add(fadeInAnimation, forKey: "animateOpacity")
        self.scatterGraph = newGraph
```

as form the above code it is seen that legends can take only one style i.e `newGraph.legend?.textStyle       = dataSourceLabelStyle` so all the text in the legends is of white color.

I want to change the legends text color also according to line color.

Can any body help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most plot types including scatter plots, set the `attributedTitle` to an `NSAttributedString` with the desired color attributes. Pie charts and bar plots have datasource methods to provide attributed legend titles for each data index.

Answer (score 0):

Do not think it is possible cause you set the legend for the graph and graph contains all your plots. Here is how I am using it in ObjC though:

```
CPTScatterPlot *aPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    aPlot.dataSource = self;
    aPlot.identifier = stringPlotId;
    [graph addPlot:aPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];   
 aPlot.title=stringPlotTitle;//will show in legends

 //add more plots if needed then format labels text once for all plots

graph.legend= [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph];
CPTMutableTextStyle *mySmallerTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
[mySmallerTextStyle setFontSize:8];
mySmallerTextStyle.color=[CPTColor whiteColor];
[graph.legend setTextStyle:(CPTTextStyle *)mySmallerTextStyle];
```